# Material table is not always being refreshed after subscribing to afterclosed event

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

**Frontend:** Angular 10 and Angular Material

**Backend:** Spring Framework 5

Based on some information I was checking about Angular tutorials, I was trying to code this flow:

**CRUD Operations**

1. Display a Dialog Component (EmployeeModal) when the user clicks "Add new" button. (Done)
2. The user completes employee information and then clicks "Save" button. I validated my REST API is responding fine and data is being stored in MySQL
   database. (Done)
3. I subscribed to afterClosed (child component) event from the parent component, so that  getEmployees method could be called from my backend again, after closing the modal dialog. By doing this, I expected to populate the local employees array with new values (result recently fetched) and to see my Material Table refreshed automatically. (Pending).
   **Note:** This approach works with delete operation, in which I invoke filter method of local array (set in parent component) and my table gets refreshed.

> ```
>     this.service.getEmployees().subscribe((employees) => {
>       this.employees = employees;
> ```

4. What I get of this method (openModal) is a little bit tricky, maybe you can give me advice to clarify a wrong concept I could have of reactive programming. In some cases, after closing the modal (Material Dialog), I get my table refreshed and log results (browser console) show me new backend values were retrieved successfully. However, in other cases the records don't get refreshed in my table, even waiting for a minute to check if it has to do with a backend delay. So, I'm kind of confused if there is something wrong with my code that refreshes table only in some cases.

```
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  titulo: string = "Employees List";
  employees: new MatTableDataSource<Employee>();

  constructor(  private service: EmployeeService,
                public dialog: MatDialog
             ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => 
        this.employees = new MatTableDataSource(employees));
  }

onOpenModal() {
  let dialog = this.dialog.open(EmployeeModal, {
      height: '400px', 
      width: '400px',
      hasBackdrop: false,
      data: { title: 'New Employee' }
  });

//I recieve this data from my child component: this.close(data)

dialog.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {

      if(data) {
        this.service.getEmployees().subscribe(employees => {
          this.employees = new MatTableDataSource(employees);
          console.log('printing new employees fetched from api');
          console.log(this.employees);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Let me know if more information could be provided. I also searched other related questions in Stack OverFlow and I think this code should work, but it fails in some cases.

Comment: Use MatTableDataSource

Comment: Use MatTableDataSource like following initialize employees:MatTableDataSource=new MatTableDataSource<Employee>();  and then assign with this.employees= new MatTableDataSource(employees);

Comment: Hello @MskSatheesh, thanks for your answer. I tried out it in my code (updated in post) and the table keeps the same values once in a while. I was thinking about a possibility, maybe you could help me clarify it. When I call "this.employees = new MatTableDataSource(employees)", inside afterClosed observable, save process seems not to have been completed yet. For that reason, in some cases when I call getEmployes method (save process completed), I get the full backend response. However, when save process hasn't been completed yet, I get an incomplete response from backend.

Comment: can you pls create stackblitz for your problem